# Реализация обработчика дефолтного нажатия enter

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не использую формы и вместо кнопок использую оформленные css-ом ссылки. Встает вопрос юзабилити, когда надо к примеру ввести логин и пароль в модальном окне и не переводя фокус из инпута нажав enter отправить данные на валидацию.

Вопрос как это удобнее реализовать, учитывая тот факт, что таких сетов в виде инпутов и дефолтной ссылки будет много. К примеру если присваивать одинаковые классы сету, то надо писать n-обработчиков на n-сетов. А хотелось бы один.

**UPD** Пока, что в голову пришел вариант отлавливать инпуты с фокусом и искать сестринский элемент ссылки-кнопки с классом default.

Минус: необходимо, чтобы они были "братьями" или хотя бы имели общего родителя, что не всегда удобно.

**UPD** Пока, что такое решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input, textarea').live('keyup', function(e){
    if(
        (this.nodeName == 'input' && e.keyCode == 13) ||
        (this.nodeName == 'textarea' && e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey)
    ){
        $(this).parents('form').eq(0).submit();
    }
});
```

Ловит input'ы и textarea в формах. Textarea отправляют только при зажатом ctrl.

Comment: Солидарен, абсолютно непонятно зачем вешать обработчик **на все** =\

Comment: С `$('input, textarea')` совершенно согласен. А вот `$(this).parents('form').eq(0).submit();`, похоже, что совсем не то что нужно ТС:

> Не использую формы и вместо кнопок использую *оформленные css-ом ссылки*.

Comment: Это уже религиозные предпочтения ТСа и ИМХО в этом нет **никакого** выйграши и смысла соответственно тоже

Comment: >совсем не то что нужно ТС

Упс, пропустил. =( А тогда я не понимаю, каким образом ТС отправляет форму. Откуда action берется?

Comment: > А тогда я не понимаю, каким образом ТС отправляет форму. Откуда action берется?

Насколько я понял просто должно вызываться событие, которое повешено на какую-либо ссылку.

Answer (score 3):

Пока получилось как-то так:

```
  $("*").keypress(function(event) {  
      if ( event.which == 13 && !(event.ctrlKey))  {             
         $("input:focus").parent().find(".default").click(); 
         $("textarea:focus").parent().find(".default").click(); 
      }   
  });

//Переопределяет enter для textarea на Ctrl+enter 
$("*").keypress(function(event) {
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.which==13)
    $("textarea:focus").val($("textarea:focus").val()+"\n");
});
```

Comment: Неплохое решение, но есть пару замечаний:

 1. Вместо `$("input:focus")` и `$("textarea:focus")` правильнее было бы использовать `$(this)`
 2. Помимо ctrlKey, по хорошему, так же нужно проверять altKey и shiftKey, т.к. shift + enter так же иногда используется для переноса строки.
 3. Так нужно вызывать `event.preventDefault()`, что бы отменить событие по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо большое - учту. Но с третим вариантом немного непонятно. Какое именно событие по умолчанию у textarea - это перенос строки по нажатию enter? Да и вообще примерчик бы небольшой не помешал бы.

Comment: > Какое именно событие по умолчанию у textarea - это перенос строки по нажатию enter?

У textarea то перенос строки, а вот у input'а отправка текущей формы формы.

Сейчас пример набросаю.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input, textarea').live('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which != 13 || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey || e.altKey) {
        return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.container').find('.default').click();
});
```

Где `.container` это родительский элемент вашей "формы".

А вместо костыля с добавлением '`\n`' по ctrl + enter я бы рекомендовал использовать shift + enter, тогда никаких дополнительных манипуляций не потребуется.

Comment: Да уже, собственно, так и сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Создай скрытый элемент с типом `submit` и не мучайся.

```
<input type="submit" style="display: none" />
```